# To POST an input using helpers

Tags: php, laravel

i'm totally new to laravel. i'm trying to POST an input from another table but in same database using Helpers. I try to get name by email using Helpers. But i got this error:
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ims\resources\views\leave\add.blade.php)

Below is my Helpers:

```
public static function getnamebyemail($id)
  {
      $userdata = DB::table('hr_intern_table')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
      if(!empty($userdata))
      {
        return $userdata->name;
      }
      return '';
  }
```

Below is the form that i try to get and post:

```
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                      <div class="form-group form-float">
                        <label for="name" class="form-label">Trainee Name</label>
                          <div class="form-line">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" disabled value="{{Helpers::getnamebyemail($data->name)}}"/>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

Below is my controller:

```
public function add($id)
  {
    $data = DB::table('leave_req_tb')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
    return view('leave.add', compact('data', 'id'));
  }



public function store_request(Request $request, $id)
  {
      $data = $this->validate($request, [
        'leave_applied'=>'required',
        'start_leave'=>'required',
        'end_leave'=>'required',
        'justification'=>'required',
        'sv_approval'=>'required',
        'hod_approval'=>'required',
        'hr_approval'=>'required',
      ]);

      DB::table('leave_req_tb')->where('id', '=', $id)->insert([
        'intern_id'=>$intern_id,
        'leave_applied'=>$request->leave_applied,
        'start_leave'=>$request->start_leave,
        'end_leave'=>$request->end_leave,
        'justification'=>$request->justification,
        'sv_approval'=>$request->sv_approval,
        'hod_approval'=>$request->hod_approval,
        'hr_approval'=>$request->hr_approval,
        'created_at' => now(),
      ]);

      return redirect('/leave/view')->with('success', 'The profile has been updated successfully.');
  }
```

I appreciate if someone can help me and explain why i got this error because i don't think there is a problem with my code.

Comment: have you try to dd($data); in your add function ?

Comment: This looks like it complaining about `$data->name`. What do you get it you `dd($data)` before the `return` statement in your `add()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Helper functions are global and don't have a class
So in your Helpers.php 
Just place the

```
function getnamebyemail($id)
{
    $userdata = DB::table('hr_intern_table')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
    if(!empty($userdata))
    {
        return $userdata->name;
    }
    return '';
}
```

along with the required imports

In your blade just use

`{{getnamebyemail($data->name)}}`